# How to unistall Fabrik from Joomla 3.4

Tags: joomla, uninstallation, joomla-component, joomla3.4

When I try to unistall [Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com/) the site goes down, look like that the unistallion routing has problems.
Any one knows how to unistall manually Fabrik without create problems to joomla?
Thanks

Comment: Is there an error message after uninstalling ? In which parts of the webiste is Fabrik used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to disable all fabrik plugins before unistall it.